# MS Word под wine. Искажаются картинки.

Tags: linux, office, wine

MS Word работает под wine. При вставке картинок исходно хорошего качества они жутко искажаются. Как от этого избавится может кто знает?

Comment: Скажите спасибо что он вообще хоть как-то запустился. Лет пять назад я пытался сделать это (запустить MSOffice под wine), но он так медленно работал, что я не мог ни слова написать в нём :D

Comment: Я давно офис под вайном юзаю. Проблем с запуском и тормозами никогда не было

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать поставить OpenOffice.

Comment: Согласен. Только сейчас лучше пробовать LibreOffice. Работает как-то постабильнее и покорректнее, чем изначальный OO.

Comment: Я и так пользуюсь обычно OO. Только вот часто после редактирования в ОО в ворде криво открывается. Особенно если есть формулы или что-то в этом роде. А это неприемлемо.

Comment: GoogleDocs ;-)

Comment: Кстати, меня однажды они просто спасили: опеноффис никак не хотел открывать один документ.. я прогнал через гуглдокс, а потом закачал обратно и открыл опеноффисом.. не сказать, что без искажений, но хоть что-то получил.